How to deal with Electron app using .asr and SteamPipe app update
I have released HTML5 Electron game on Steam. It's easy to update game as SteamPipe compare files and upload those which has changed. So changing .js files gives few KB update.
Recently I have started to build app using ELectron command 'npm run make' which compress all **src ** folder into 1 big .asr file. I know it's recommended to use .asr compression but how to make app updates on Steam?? Each time upload whole .asr file? I'm totally lost how to deal with it.
I can keep media file sin .asr but few .js files I'm updating often. Should I exclude it from .asr compression?
I have tried few tutorials regarding files excluding but nothing works. Nothing is created in asr.uncompressed folder.

The format you're referring to is Electron's Archive Format "ASAR." This has a known format and file layout (see the previous link). However, Electron also provides a tool for anyone to inspect and extract ASAR archives. So note that packaging to ASAR does not provide any protection for your assets and source code whatsoever.
Reading Steam's documentation it seems as though you'd need to make sure that changes between two versions of your ASAR align in 1 MB blocks. This does not seem to currently be possible with ASAR's API.
Therefore, it's up to you. You'll need to decide whether a nice and tidy app folder for your game is more important to you than atomic updates.
